# Spring-boot 2 and swagger 2 (springfox) does not show model

Tags: json, spring-boot, swagger-2.0

I have created my patch endpoint (Json path specified in RFC 6902).
At UI generated by springfox my endpoint is shown, but the model example (only patch) did not show.

To use Json patch in my Spring-boot 2 project I have used that dependency on pom.xml.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.java-json-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-patch</artifactId>
        <version>1.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>           
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

At my endpoint, my code is:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/operation", produces = "application/json")
public class IntentController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", 
                        method = RequestMethod.PATCH, 
                        consumes = "application/json-patch+json")
    public void updateValue(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody JsonPatch patch){ {
        // ... do magic
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", 
                    method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public MyDto getValue(@PathVariable Long id){ {
           MyDto dto = service.findById(id);                
           return dto;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void updateValue(@RequestBody MyDto dto){ {
           service.insert(dto);
    }

}
```

My GET and POST endpoints are generated fine with their example models in UI.

Only PATCH doesn't work fine... their example model didn't generate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies with `JsonPatch` object, this object does not have any getter method, so `Springfox` library could not generate the model for request.

One possible solution may be like , you create a custom `MyJsonPatch` POJO with getter and setter and create a `JsonPatch` with the data of `MyJsonPatch`.

Comment: It's a good idea, but I think this not work for me. Because JsonPath is a complex object. To workaround, I decide to use @ApiParam to document that this field is an RFC 6902.

Answer (score 0):

I can't found a solution to my problem, so I decided to use @ApiParam from Swagger to describe that this field is an RFC 6902 implementation.